# request member for 'name' in something not structure or union

Tags: c, struct, structure

i have this two structures

```
typedef struct pokemon_move_t {
char* name;
PokemonType type;
int power_points, max_power_points;
int strength;
} *PokemonMove; 

typedef struct pokemon_t {
char* name;
PokemonType type;
int experience;
int health_points;
PokemonMove* moves;
int number_of_moves, max_number_of_moves;
} *Pokemon;
```

and i have a function that receives pokemon struct and i'm trying to reach the name field in the function and it shows me the error message in the title,i tried everything that suggested before and it didn't work, the function is(not complete) :

```
int pokemonMoveName(Pokemon pokemon){
char* name= pokemon->moves->name;   //the error is in this line
return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Use `PokemonMove moves;` instead of `PokemonMove* moves;`

Comment: Do not hide pointer nature behind a typedef.  It causes a lot of confusion, such as you have just experienced for yourself.

Comment: `char* name= (*pokemon->moves)->name;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element `moves` is:

```
PokemonMove * moves;
```

Which is:

```
struct pokemon_move_t ** moves;
```

And not:

```
struct pokemon_move_t * moves;
```

... it is a pointer to a pointer to a structure and not to a structure itself.

I think that you don't want this!

Either you have to remove the `*` at the `typedef` or the `*` in the struct.

If `moves` really is a pointer to a pointer you'll have to access it the following way (or similar):

```
char* name= (*(pokemon->moves))->name;
```

... which is equal to:

```
char* name= pokemon->moves[0]->name;
```

... or, if `moves` points to an array:

```
char* name= pokemon->moves[index]->name;
```

Comment: the problem is that i can't edit the structures , it had been given to us by the staff of the course and all i can edit is the function, you know how can i do it without changing the structures ?

Comment: @SherazFaraj: you could have mentioned that restriction in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean the following declaration of the data member

```
typedef struct pokemon_t {
char* name;
PokemonType type;
int experience;
int health_points;
PokemonMove moves;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
int number_of_moves, max_number_of_moves;
} *Pokemon;
```

In this case this statement

```
char* name= pokemon->moves->name;
```

will be valid.

The type `PokemonMove` is already declared like a pointer type.

```
typedef struct pokemon_move_t {
char* name;
PokemonType type;
int power_points, max_power_points;
int strength;
} *PokemonMove; 
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```